# How hike messenger is auto inviting WhatsApp group users and importing WhatsApp chats?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, accessibility

I recently witnessed hike (beta) auto inviting friends via WhatsApp & importing WhatsApp chats to hike on my friend's non-rooted phone. Till then, I was under the impression that inter app data access on a non-rooted android phone was pretty much non existent unless you explicitly grant them.
Here the only extra thing hike requests is android accessibility permissions (notification & window). How is hike achieving this?

Even the Accessibility Api is quite restrictive & does not allow simulating touch events. And while importing hike shows one view written encrypting data & doesn't even bring up WhatsApp to front to read window content.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot? (Please hide any sensitive or personal information from the screenshot.)

Comment: Related Question: **[Can Hike messenger steal our whatsapp data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186205/can-hike-messenger-steal-our-whatsapp-data)**

Comment: Hm.. someone is getting bothered.. https://www.xda-developers.com/google-threatening-removal-accessibility-services-play-store/

Comment: Seems like simulating touch event is supported. Then they could use this and window content reader to crack the content from other apps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283640/how-does-the-api-24-accessibilityservice-dispatchgesture-method-work