# Can Hike Messenger steal WhatsApp data?

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger, privacy, accessibility, hike-messenger

As per the new update of [Hike](https://hike.in/) messenger, it gives a reward up to **₹10000** for making your friend join Hike. To do this, Hike asks for accessibility permission. And when you refer a friend or a group, all messages start showing in Hike. So now I guess Hike can read all WhatsApp text messages and media shared.

But the problem is that after getting accessibility permission, it can read all the notifications, even OTPs of our transaction. So how can I assure my security and privacy? Is it a big concern or am I missing something with their terms and condition?

Comment: So why on Earth would you ever use Hike? Just use Signal or something... Honestly, their T&C are ridiculous on the rights they and their "third-party" affiliates have over your information, pictures, voice, name, and everything else related to anything you do in Hike, perpetually (forever) and for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that after getting accessibility permission, it can read all the notifications, even OTPs of our transaction. So how can I assure my security and privacy?

Turn off **SMS, NOTIFICATION ACCESS** permissions to that app.

[image]